# Скорость медленная очень. MySQL база

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Установил Xampp и стартанул через MySQL server. Есть база, таблицы в форматах *.idb, *.frm, db.opt. Их просто скопировал(сервер MySQl отключен) в папку xampp(туда где хранится файлы базы MySQL) и сделал upgrade. Запустил сервер обратно и через навикат подключился к базе. Все таблицы видны(открываю таблицу все данные есть), легкие запросы выполняется. А когда сложные запросы задаю, очень очень долго выполняется, может и не выполняется, ни разу не получилось до конца. (проблема не в запросах 100% уверен, потому что раньше максимум за 5 минут выполнялись, а сейчас даже 2 часа не выполняется). Подскажите что может быть причиной этой проблемы? раньше сделал дамп. данное время пытаюсь через навикат восстановить базу из bd.sql (15гб)...уже 3 день жду когда закончится восстановление.[image: процесс восстановление]

```
># Example MySQL config file for small systems.
>#
># This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
># from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
># doesn't use much resources.
>#
># You can copy this file to
># F:/Xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
># mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
># installation this directory is F:/Xampp/mysql/data) or
># ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
>#
># In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
># If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
># with the "--help" option.
># The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
>[client] 
># password       = your_password 
>port            = 3306 
>socket          = "F:/Xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
># Here follows entries for some specific programs 
># The MySQL server
>[mysqld]
>port= 3306
>socket = "F:/Xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
>basedir = "F:/Xampp/mysql" 
>tmpdir = "F:/Xampp/tmp" 
>datadir = "F:/Xampp/mysql/data"
>pid_file = "mysql.pid"
># enable-named-pipe
>key_buffer = 16M
>max_allowed_packet = 1M
>sort_buffer_size = 512K
>net_buffer_length = 8K
>read_buffer_size = 256K
>read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
>myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
>log_error = "mysql_error.log"
># Change here for bind listening
># bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
># bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6
># Where do all the plugins live
>plugin_dir = "F:/Xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 
># Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
># if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
># All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
># Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
># (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
># 
># commented in by lampp security
>#skip-networking
>#skip-federated
># Replication Master Server (default)
># binary logging is required for replication
># log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
>#log-bin=mysql-bin
># required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
># defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
># but will not function as a master if omitted
>server-id  = 1
># Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
>#
># To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
># two methods :
>#
># 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
>#    the syntax is:
>#
>#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
>#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
>#
>#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
>#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
>#
>#    Example:
>#
>#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
>#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
>#
># OR
>#
># 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
>#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
>#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
>#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
>#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
>#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
>#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
>#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
>#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
>#
># required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
># (and different from the master)
># defaults to 2 if master-host is set
># but will not function as a slave if omitted
>#server-id       = 2
>#
># The replication master for this slave - required
>#master-host     =   <hostname>
>#
># The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
># to the master - required
>#master-user     =   <username>
># The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
># the master - required
>#master-password =   <password>
># The port the master is listening on.
># optional - defaults to 3306
>#master-port     =  <port>
># binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
>#log-bin=mysql-bin
># Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
>#tmpdir = "F:/Xampp/tmp"
>#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname
># Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
>#bdb_cache_size = 4M
>#bdb_max_lock = 10000
># Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
>#skip-innodb
>innodb_data_home_dir = "F:/Xampp/mysql/data"
>innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
>innodb_log_group_home_dir = "F:/Xampp/mysql/data"
>#innodb_log_arch_dir = "F:/Xampp/mysql/data"
>## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
>## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
>innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80%
>innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 4M
>## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
>vinnodb_log_file_size = 5M
>innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
>innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
>innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
>## UTF 8 Settings
>v#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
>#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
>#character_set_server=utf8
>#skip-character-set-client-handshake
>#character_sets-dir="F:/Xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
>[mysqldump]
>quick
>max_allowed_packet = 16M
>[mysql]
>no-auto-rehash
># Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
>#safe-updates
>[isamchk]
>key_buffer = 20M
>sort_buffer_size = 20M
>read_buffer = 2M
>write_buffer = 2M
>[myisamchk]
>key_buffer = 20M
>sort_buffer_size = 20M
>read_buffer = 2M
>write_buffer = 2M
>       [mysqlhotcopy]
>        interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Конфигурацию сервера в студию, размеры таблиц в студию, небольшой пример обрабатываемых данных в студию, explain в студию. А восстановление из sql-файла по определению должно быть долгим, потому что это выполнение обычных sql-запросов со всеми проверками и пересчётами индексов

Comment: Конфиги ноутбука это неинтересно, интересна конфигурация mysql-сервера

Comment: Где-то в файле my.cnf. Судя по вашему вопросу, вам нужно погуглить тему тюнинга настроек сервера - одно только увеличение доступной мускулю оперативки способно увеличить производительность в несколько раз в некоторых ситуациях

Comment: добавил инфо из файла my.ini

Comment: Попробуйте поменять конфиг - тут примеры https://ruhighload.com/my.cnf . У вас прямо в конфиге указана ключевая опция `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 80%` , а вы уверены что парсер конфига понимает единицу измерения '%'? Я вот нет - обычно всёгда всё пишут в `M`

Comment: сейчас поставил innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G , надо ли перезагрузить сервер (просто процесс идет, а окончании этого процесса жду уже 3день)?

Comment: @Elaman Razakov наберите в консоли `service mysql reload`  - только если у вас один толстый запрос столько выполняется, доходить до конца он будет на старом конфиге, кажется. Вру. У вас же windows - там по-другому конфиг релодить, гуглите)